# Oracle XE connection configuration for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and am currently having a problem with configuring config/database.yml to connect Oracle XE 11g R2. I need your help!

```
Here is my setup:
VirtualBox 4.3.6
Ubuntu 64 v12.04.3

$ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.2

$ gem -v
2.2.2

$ gem install ruby-oci8
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ruby-oci8-2.1.7
Parsing documentation for ruby-oci8-2.1.7
Done installing documentation for ruby-oci8 after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

# Oracle XE 11gR2 installed in a different VM (Host: 10.1.1.3)
#
$ ruby -r oci8 -e 'OCI8.new("ruby/ruby@10.1.1.3").exec("select * from session_privs") do |r| puts r.join(","); end'
CREATE SESSION
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE TYPE
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE
```

Note that I can verify connection using the command above. However, I cannot create a new model using the "rails generate model Post title:string text:text" command - I get a long list of errors which complain that my "adapter" is not valid.

Questions:

Q1. What do I have to put in the Gemfile?

Q2. Should I see ruby-oci8 gem in the output of the command "bundle install" - currently I can see "Using sqlite3 (1.3.9) and there also 2 entries in the Gemfile as follows:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Q3. Has anyone successfully configured database.yml to work with Oracle XE? Please share it with me.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Roobie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having ruby-oci8 installed is often the hard bit, so you're nearly there.

Activerecord needs an *adapter* to talk to any kind of database; for oracle you will want [oracle enhanced](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced).

So add this to your Gemfile then redo bundle install:

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
```

Read the linked page for oracle-specific quirks.  Your database.yml file should look like this:

```
database:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: //10.1.1.3:1521/XE
  username: ruby
  password: ruby
```

The "XE" in the database connection string is the SID.  I *think* with oracle XE the SID is always "XE" but I don't have one handy and haven't used it since 10g.

You shouldn't need to add ruby-oci8 to your gemfile because the oracle adapter declares it as a dependency, but it doesn't hurt to add it.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That works for me. Actually, I have tried both //10.1.1.3:1521/XE and omitted the leading "//" i.e. 10.1.1.3:1521/XE - both work. Thank you very much!